# getting caller's id within jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'd some experience in jquery but learning plugin creation right now. I've following javascript in html page

```
$("#testid").myplugin({});
```

In JQuery plugin, I have following code:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.siddeffect = function (options) {
        console.log(this.attr('id'));
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        return this;
    };
})( jQuery );
```

I'm getting following in console

```
undefined
undefined
```

I tried few other combination as well but do not getting id ('testid' in above example). IS there any way to get calling id/selector within plugin?

**PS:  is present in html, as only element in body.**

Comment: what is the value of this ? is it what you expect it to be ?

Comment: what `myplugin` is? because if you call `$("#testid").siddeffect ({});` it will display `testid`.

Comment: Just a quick typo edit.
$.fn.siddeffect is actually $.fn.myplugin. So myplugin is name of plugin as well as function in plugin JS

Comment: Ok in this case you don't have any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think

```
$("#testid").myplugin({});
```

should be

```
$("#testid").siddeffect({});
```

**Or**

`$.fn.siddeffect` should change to `$.fn.myplugin`.

#### I think you have typos in your original document.

Your code is working just fine. **[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/Czest/3/)**.

Comment: Thanks, there were typo mistakes. +1 for help and quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, except that your calling "myplugin" instead of "siddeffect". Anyway, It works fine here:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pHqDF/3/)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, there were typo mistakes. +1 for help and quick reply.